# TypeError: Initialization arguments are not supported error django celery

Tags: python, django, celery, django-haystack

Im getting an error from django-celery that has had me totally stumped for the best part of a day now.

IM using django-haystack and have a celery task that gets run whenever a model that is part of the search index is updated.  I have a custom QueuedSearchIndex class that connect to the models post_save and post_delete signals.  This works fine for one model but not another which is the User model from django.contrib.auth

When a user model is created / updated the following error appears from celery.

```
Problem installing fixture '/believein/data/www/platform/believein/fixtures/user.json': Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/believein/data/python-virtualenvs/believein-platform/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 196, in handle    obj.save(using=using)
  File "/believein/data/python-virtualenvs/believein-platform/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 165, in save    models.Model.save_base(self.object, using=using, raw=True)
  File "/believein/data/python-virtualenvs/believein-platform/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 565, in save_base
    created=(not record_exists), raw=raw, using=using)
  File "/believein/data/python-virtualenvs/believein-platform/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 172, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/believein/data/www/platform/main/utils/search.py", line 156, in update_object
    update_search_index.delay(self, instance, self.backend)
  File "/believein/data/python-virtualenvs/believein-platform/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 343, in delay
    return self.apply_async(args, kwargs)
  File "/believein/data/python-virtualenvs/believein-platform/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 469, in apply_async
    **options)
  File "/believein/data/python-virtualenvs/believein-platform/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/amqp.py", line 214, in publish_task
    **kwargs)
  File "/believein/data/python-virtualenvs/believein-platform/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 150, in publish
    compression, headers)
  File "/believein/data/python-virtualenvs/believein-platform/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 201, in _prepare
    body) = encode(body, serializer=serializer)
  File "/believein/data/python-virtualenvs/believein-platform/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 153, in encode
    payload = encoder(data)
  File "/believein/data/python-virtualenvs/believein-platform/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 71, in _reduce_ex
    state = base(self)
TypeError: Initialization arguments are not supported
```

As you can see this example was raised when loading fixtures but its the same when editing the model normally.  This is the case for both new instances of User and updating instances that exist already.  My task looks like the following

```
@task                                                                                                                                                                                                           
def update_search_index(index, instance, backend):                                                                                                                                                              
"""task to update the solr index when a model is updated                                                                                                                                                    

:param index: instance of the ``SearchIndex``                                                                                                                                                               
:param instance: the model that was updated                                                                                                                                                                 
:type instance: ``django.db.models.Model``                                                                                                                                                                  
:param backend: the search back instance                                                                                                                                                                    
:type backend: ``haystack.backends.solr_backend``                                                                                                                                                           

see ``main.utils.search.QueuedSearchIndex`` for more info                                                                                                                                                   

"""                                                                                                                                                                                                         

backend.update(index, [instance])
```

The searchindex class looks like the following

```
class QueuedSearchIndex(RealTimeSearchIndex):                                                                                                                                                                   

def update_object(self, instance, **kwargs):                                                                                                                                                                
    """Handles updating the index when a model is updated by pushing                                                                                                                                        
    the update through celery                                                                                                                                                                               

    :param instance: the instance of the model that was updated                                                                                                                                             
    :type instance: django.db.models.Model                                                                                                                                                                  

    """                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    if self.should_update(instance, **kwargs):                                                                                                                                                              
        update_search_index.delay(self, instance, self.backend)
```

It may be worth mentioning that the User model has a One2One relationship with a UserProfile model that has a post_save signal on the User model to create UserProfile instance if one dosent already exist.

Comment: One thing I can point out is your decorator should be `@task()` It would be nice to know if your function works without a celery decorator. It's always nice to start without one.

Comment: The error appears to be in serialization. I would recommend passing model class and id instead of the model object itself and grabbing the latter from the database in the task code.

Comment: @atereshkin  You are correct,  I switched the task to pass the model_name and instance id then garb them inside of the task which has resolved the issue.  If you would like to answer i will accept